# How can I render UTF-8 characters?

Tags: nodes, breadcrumbs

In nodes, the *'* character is rendered like *’*. Instead of Poland characters, a question mark is shown. In breadcrumbs, *'* is rendered as '.

I tried the following code, but nothing works.

```php
<?php print stripslashes(render($content));?>
```

```php
<?php print html_entity_decode($term->description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
```

How can I make my page work with all special characters?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons for that behavior. The most likely one is that your database encoding does not support these characters.

You should use a UTF8 encoding as standard character set (collation).

Comment: My database uses UTF8 encoding. So maybe that's not problem here?

Comment: In that case, I do need some more information: What is your used PHP version and do you have PHP's mbstring extension installed and enabled (you will find that information in the output of phpinfo()), which document headers are sent to your browser, does your theme use custom fonts for displaying your pages?